# dwonload attached .text file from database with php not working

Tags: php, database, download, blob

I have the problem using the following code,I do not know what i did wrong. I want to download link for the file name from MySQL database

```
<tr>                        
<td>Employee Name</td>
<td>Project Name</td>
<td>Module Name</td>
<td>Task Name</td>
<td>File Attached</td>
</tr>

<?php
header("Content-type: plain text");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file_attachment");
foreach($tel as $data){    
echo "<tr><td>"."<a href>".$data[file_attachment]."</td></tr>";
} ?>
```

when i load this page the output like download the HTML document of the page.....
Please anyone suggest to me, how to achieve a download link for the stored text file from database.

Comment: create a text file in root directory and update the link in database. don't store files in database untill necessary

Comment: how to do update the link in db and how to download the file . will you give some sample...

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You have to header, before there is any output, so before you send any HTML.
Second: You use HTML by purpose? I just ask, because you want to generate a textfile, I guess a CSV, so my anwer will assume this.
So, what I would do is something like this:

```
<?php
    $output = 'Employee Name;Project Name;Module Name;Task Name;File Attached'; //The headline of the CSV to explain the entries
    $tel = array();
    foreach($tel as $data){
        $output .= PHP_EOL . ';' . $data["emp_name"] . ';' . $data["proj_name"] . ';' . $data["mod_name"] . ';' . $data["task_name"] . ';' . $data["file_attachment"];
    }

    $type = "text/csv";
    $size = strlen( $output );
    $filename = "table.csv";

    header("Content-type: " . $type);
    header("Content-length: " . $size);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
    header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Ah sorry, missunderstood the question. I would follow the comment of @Sundar. Save the file as a file in your webspace and save a link to this file in your DB.

Comment: I already store the text file in db. my question is how to download the stored file from db. I dnt know my coding is right or wrong... please guide me right way.... thanks